# Create DataTemplate at runtime using c# for windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, datatemplate

How to dynamically create a DataTemplate with a UIElement in c# for windows 8 such as:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Button />
</DataTemplate>
```

To be done like this:

```
DataTemplate dataTemplate = new DataTemplate();
...
...
...
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataTemplate` belongs to XAML part of the page because you can not alter them from simple run time APIs. There's no way to define `DataTemplate` from C# except this.

```
private DataTemplate CreateDataTemplate()
{
    const string xaml = "<DataTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"><Button /></DataTemplate>";
    var dt = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(xaml);
    return dt;
}
```